# How to restart a MapReduce Task attemp

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i have a Hadoop cluster (version 1.0.3) and some certain analyses. For some reasons, the map task can decide, weather it is reasonable to run through the data on this specific node. If it's yes, the job will run some scientific analyses.
If not, it would be nice to reschedule this map task attempt on a different node. I can even predict which node will be reasonable for a restart of the map task.
I don't want to use the skipping feature, since the data is not bad and shouldn't be skipped. But it would be appropriate, if the specific data will be processed again at the end of the map phase.

Do you have any suggestions?

Greetings

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to write your own scheduler for this requirement. You can't just start and reschedule tasks from a job.

Comment: All failed task attempts are restarted automatically on different or same node based on availability. And there is a property in hadoop to configure number of task attempts or retries. And there is also a property to set tolerance which says: until x% task fail don't stop or else stop or keep reattempting based on how other properties are configured.  Properties of interests would be : "mapred.max.map.failures.percent and mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent and mapred.map.max.attempts"

Comment: But that would mean, i set the fail rate so high and waiting until the task will be scheduled a proper node. This doesn't seam very elegant. And i will get an unreasonable high fail rate giving a wrong impression on the state of the job.
But thanks for your answers.